# Mac often says no internet - comes back after WiFi restart

Tags: wireless-networking

I have noticed this phenomenon in 2 of my Macbooks. After I come back after a while (2-3 days), they say "No internet" while still being connected to my WiFi. My phone / other devices on the same wifi work just fine. Turning on/off wifi and reconnecting to same network fixes it. Someone else suggested to try "Renew DHCP Lease" but that does not work either. What could be happening?

Comment: Maybe it's your default DNS server that is a little flaky? Try using other DNS servers. Go to Network prefs>Advanced>DNS tab>DNS Servers on the left. Remove the current IP address and add the following three: 1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8